# Ставятся ли запятые на месте пропусков?

Tags: запятые

***"Я не хотела вмешиваться, но (?) как подруга (?) я не могла игнорировать его состояние".***

Сочетание "как подруга" используется в прямом смысле, героиня не сравнивается с подругой, а правда является ей.

Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Я не хотела вмешиваться, но, **как подруга**, я не могла игнорировать его состояние.*

**Пояснение**

1. **[Розенталь, пункт 3(1)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147)**:

Сравнительный оборот может содержать в себе оттенок **причинного** значения: ***Как старший**, приказываю вам, господа, немедленно разойтись* (Купр.).

2. Сравнительный оборот имеет значение **"в качестве подруги"** и   обычно не обособляется, пункт 4 (3). Но обособление возможно при  подчеркивании **причинного** значения (**так как** я его подруга, будучи его подругой).

**Пример:**

Н. А. Морозов. Повести моей жизни/ На перепутье (1912)

*Я по-прежнему мог бы любить эту девушку, как полюбил ее платонически два года назад, когда она явилась к нам в дом как гувернантка моих младших сестер, но только при одном условии: чтобы она не была явно приставлена ко мне, как теперь, в виде сторожа, а пошла бы вместе со мною, **как подруга жизни**, делить и радости, и горе.*

Comment: Желательно еще убрать второе "я", повтор не нужен.